# Using Bitbucket Repo for Repositories

Tags: maven, bitbucket

I'm trying to use repository to my bitbucket repository like

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>project-repository</id>
            <url>https://bitbucket.org/myUser/myproject-repo/raw/master</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and using dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-repo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

when i install maven project always  got warning
    Checksum validation failed, expected  but is d59f895f5fb8c06d76c530a55745203458028a78

and my local repo .pom always got  tag
anyone know what problem it is. and how i can get the solution using bitbucket as maven repositories.
Big Thanks

Comment: I never heard anybody using bitbucket as Maven repository. If this not a special function of bitbucket, but a git repository, then it cannot be done. Usually, people use Nexus or Artifactory as Maven repositories.

Comment: yeah you right.. just want to know. it's already solved btw. thanks